# How find Twitter or G+ account associated with email address?

Tags: php, email, twitter, google-plus

Is there any way, how to find twitter or G+ account associated with email address?

I have database of email adressess and i wanna get from these data more informations about that people. So i wanna find people social profiles asociated to that email adressess. Can you please help me how? Ideally in PHP or any REST API.

I'm not interrested to any paid tools like Vibeapp.co etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this, it's a privacy issue. The paid tools do it by buying up user lists from things like Farmville.